# Ajax запрос выполняется несколько раз

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

есть ajax запрос

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       var btn = $('.open-modal-btn'),
         btn.on('click', function() {
                        modal.fadeIn();
                        var regi = $('#region').val();
                        var addr = $('#address').val();
                        $('#regi').empty().append(regi);
                        $('#addr').empty().append(addr);
                        $('#request').click(function () {
                           $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "savetable.php",
                               data: {  region: $('#region').val(),
                                        fulladdress: $('#address').val() + ' подъезд ' + $('#entrance').val() + ' этаж ' + $('#level').val() + ' офис ' +  $('#office').val(),
                                        cityphone: $('#cityphone').val(),
                                        intphone: $('#intphone').val()
                               },
                               success: function (data) {
                                   alert('Запись сохранена');
                                   console.log(data);
                                   modal.fadeOut();
                               },
                               error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError);
                               }
                           });
                        });

                    });
    });
```

файл savetable.php

```
if(isset($_POST['fulladdress']) && isset($_POST['region'])){
    $res = array();
    $region = strip_tags(($_POST['region']));
    $faddress = strip_tags(($_POST['fulladdress']));
    $cityphone = strip_tags($_POST['cityphone']);
    $intphone = strip_tags($_POST['intphone']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM reg_office_area WHERE area = '".$region."'";
    $request = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        $res['id'] = $row['id'];
        $res['area'] = $row['area'];
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO reg_office(id_area,city_name,city_phone,int_phone,address) VALUES ('".$res['id']."','".$region."','".$cityphone."','".$intphone."','".$faddress."')";
    $request = mysql_query($query);

}else{
    echo 'Вы не заполнили все поля';
}
```

После того как я нажимаю на элемент #request , происходит INSERT строки в БД.
Если я нажимаю на элемент #request второй раз, заполняю поля , происходит INSERT 2-х одинаковых строк, если третий раз INSERT 3-х строк и т.д, 
если обновить страницу то все начинается с начала, сначала одна строка потом две и  т.д.

Почему это происходит? Как это поправить?

Comment: уникальное поле в таблице - чтобы не было дублей.
по повторным запросам - click срабатывает более одного раза вероятно
повесьте другое событие

Comment: Разметку в вопрос добавть

Comment: `btn.on('click', function() { ` после каждого клика вешает событие `$('#request').click(function () {`, поэтому клик на #request срабатывает столько раз, сколько кликнули на btn

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev а как это вынести ? у меня надо сначало нажать на btn чтобы появилось модальное окно, а на нём кнопка #request

Comment: у вас эта кнопка есть независимо от того, открыто ли модальное. Поэтому вешайте `$('#request').click` в `$(document).ready`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev все понял спасибо, можете оформить как ответ я вам плюсик поставлю